# Underflow using Eigensystem for large mass and stiffness matrix with large stiffness values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am trying to use the `Eigensystem` command to determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a multi-degree of freedom system. Currently, I have a mass matrix and a stiffness matrix, both square matrices with dimensions $90x90$; however, I aim to increase their size even further by increasing the number of degrees of freedom. My problem is that most values in my stiffness matrix are of the order of 10^17, while my mass matrix has values less than 10^3. I was able to determine the eigenvalues/eigenvectors for the same problem but with fewer degrees of freedom (smaller matrices) by setting the precision of the matrices myself, using:

`Eigensystem[{SetPrecision[StiffnessMatrix, 500], SetPrecision[MassMatrix, 500]}];`,

However, I still get underflow errors when I set the precision to $20,000$; any higher I go, it becomes too slow. Is there a way around this issue or a smarter way of doing it? This is the link to the Wolfram Mathematica forum, where I have attached a code file with the $2$ matrices because they are too large to paste them here directly:

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3127249?p_p_auth=wsm2G1Xf

Thanks for your help.

Comment: any reason you are using `Eigensystem` and not `NDEigensystem` ?

Comment: I am fairly new to Mathematica so I am not entirely sure what `NDEigensystem` does and how to use it with 2 numeric matrices

Comment: Can you rescale your matrices so that they have more reasonable values? You may have to rescale the eigenvalues as a consequence but that is allowed.  Perhaps it would be better to let us know the ratio of the minimum absolute value to the maximum absolute value. Also, do you know if your matrices are symmetric and positive definite? You are talking about mass and stiffness matrices so I am wondering if you are expecting the eigenvalues to be natural frequencies squared and positive and definitely not complex.

Comment: I have had a look at your matrices. I note that the mass matrix is degenerate.  If you run `Eigensystem` on just your mass matrix you will see that many of the eigenvalues are zero. I think this is why when you look at the eigenvalues of your full problem, without the `SetPrecision`  you get ComplexInfinity for some of the eigenvalues. In vibration terms many of natural frequencies are infinite.

Comment: Hi Hugh, thanks for your helpful comments. It appears that my matrices may be flawed after all, but nonetheless, by doing a Singular Value Decomposition pre-conditioning step solves my issue. `{us, σs, vs} = SingularValueDecomposition[StiffnessMatrix];
{um,σm, vm} = SingularValueDecomposition[MassMatrix];
sm2 = us .σs . vs\[ConjugateTranspose];
mm2 = um .σm . vm\[ConjugateTranspose];
EigenSystem[{sm2, mm2}]`